# How to get product URL or URL alias using product ID?

Tags: commerce, uri

I'm using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and stuck in this problem. I'm creating a custom module that will display a product title and some info.

I want that product to be linked to its node page, and product Object is all I have to my resources. I'm thinking of getting the product URL or alias using `product_id` but I don't know how. I already searched it but there's nothing clear on the search results I got.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error I found a solution. Here's what I did.

```
        //$product is the product object that I mentioned above
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $product);
        $nodes   = $wrapper->field_product_node->value();
        $path    = drupal_get_path_alias("node/".$nodes[0]->nid);
        $product->path = $path;
```